# Call 2 jQuery functions from 1 event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm launching a jquery dialog, which displays some links. on click of the links, i want to display something on an element via ajax, and close the dialog.

here are the two snippets, which i cannot figure out how to combine.

```
//this is the handler and the ajax function
$(document).delegate("a[rel=link]", "click", function() {
    $("#target").load($(this).attr("href"));
    return false;
});
//this function i want to add to the above handler
function() {
    $(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
    return false
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that 'this' refers to the same thing in both snippets:

```
//this is the combined function
$(document).delegate("a[rel=link]", "click", function() {
$("#target").load($(this).attr("href"));
$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I spent the last hour messing with it and could not get anything. Thanks again.